# Django: Concurrent access to settings.py

Tags: python, django, concurrency

I am not sure whether I have to care about concurrency, but I didn't find any documentation about it.

I have some data stored at my `settings.py` like ip addresses and each user can take one or give one back. So I have read and write operations and I want that only one user read the file at the same moment.

How could I handle this?

And yes, I want to store the data at the `settings.py`. I found also the module `django-concurrency`. But I couldn't find anything at the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as e4c5 mentioned, conventionally settings.py is pretty light on logic.  The loading mechanism for settings is pretty obscure and, I personally, like to stay away from things that are difficult to understand and interact with :)

You absolutely have to care about concurrency.  How are you running your application?  It's tricky because in the dev env you have a simple server and usually handle only a handful of requests at the same time (and a couple years ago the dev server was single threaded)

If you're running your application using a forking server, how will you share data between processes? one process won't even see the other processes `settings.py` changes.  I'm not even sure of how it would look like with a threading server, but it would probably at least require a source code audit of your web server to understand the specifics of how requests are handled and how memory is shared.

Using a DB is by far the easiest solution, (you should be able to use an in memory db as an option too memcache/redis/etc).  DB's provide concurrency support out the box and will be a lot more easier to reason about and provides primitives for concurrent accessing of data.  And in the case of redis, which is single threaded you won't even have to worry about concurrent accesses to your shared IP addresses

Answer (score 1):

> And yes, I want to store the data at the settings.py.

No you definitely don't want to do that. the settings.py file is configuring django and any pluggable apps that you may use with it. it's not intended to be used as a place for dumping data. Data goes into a database.

And don't forget that the settings.py file is usually read only once.

Comment: I use also a database, but I want this kind of data stored at a text file.

Comment: Then use a text file! :)

Comment: So it is better to use a extra text file as the settings.py? Why?

Comment: no you should be using the database. You are just reinventing the wheel here. Your question mentions concurrency. If you use a text file you have to deal with that. Why write all that (potentially buggy) code when teh database gives you all of it for free?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But some people want to change data on the server with vim.

Comment: I don't really see what that has got to do wtih django

Comment: I want to store data at a text file, so somebody could change it with vim. And Django can access at the text files.